# how to change the focus of tabbaritem on iphone

Tags: iphone

i have 4  items in tabbar controller now bydeafult 1st item is selected  now how to change this so that i can show 4th item by default whenever my app start  .

this is too simple but i cant figure it out    and how to listen to whenevr items are pressed ??

right now i can load a view based on tap but i want that code like

```
if(tabbar.button==2)


 then do this...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Either use this code or Follow the below Link:

NSArray *array;
array = [[self tabBarController] viewControllers];
    // This is a test where I programmatically select the tab AND the switch.
[[[array objectAtIndex:2] switches] setSelectedSegmentIndex:4];
[[self tabBarController] setViewControllers:array];

Solution of your problem is posted on this link ,
Just follow this Link :
[How to switch between UITabBarController programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152752/how-to-switch-between-uitabbarcontroller-programmatically)